# How to access home screen settings with Galaxy S5 Neo?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, home-screen

I just bought the new Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo that has Android 5.1.1 as the default OS OOTB.

First thing I noticed is that the home screen transition effects are gone (3D rotation/card stack) so I wanted to turn them on. This proved hard as I can't find how to access the home screen settings where the transition effects can be enabled/disabled.

I tried to press and hold on empty home screen (the way it was done with my previous phone Galaxy S3) but the only options there are themes, widgets and wallpapers so home screen settings is missing.

Does anyone know where I can turn on those transition effects?

**EDIT:** It also seems that there is some micro lag and stutter when quickly swiping home screens or application menu screens. I tried out a few custom launchers and I noticed that the micro lag is gone. I can only assume that the problem lies within the TouchWiz version? Maybe some bug?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Anything in the Settings Page? In some devices, there's a *Home* or *Launcher* section.

Comment: @Huey Nope haven't found anything.. it seems that the TouchWiz version of Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo is just missing those transition effects and the whole settings page for the home screen. It also has annoying lag. I've been using Nova Launcher for now while waiting for answer or updates for the TouchWiz problems. :)